# Can the y-axis value be greater than 1 fter using density=True in plt.hist function?

Tags: matplotlib

In the following code using `density=True` gives probability density function whose area under the curve is equal to 1. I want to make sure on y-axis I'm getting values greater than 1. Shouldn't it be in the range of [0,1]? I have used similar Ls data even in some cases area under the curve is `1.00000002`. Can we get such value greater than 1 after using `density=True`?

```
`Ls= np.array([0.28904281, 0.07674593 ,0.1602232 , 
0.91125812, 0.31972387, 0.44688592, 5.91075163 
,0.52440172, 0.51376938, 0.16481705 ,0.35505426, 
0.4354722, 5.79930666 ,0.19999694, 
6.86172285, 0.44483234 ,0.30679022 
,0.68441839,0.58445867 ,0.32532547, 0.3061434,  
0.33319276, 0.26755858, 0.40010735,0.53881366 
,0.07560947, 0.29215042, 0.39045618, 0.27220402, 
0.8472669,0.11772259 ,0.20980161, 0.31013296, 
0.60890591, 5.78487512, 0.5614211,0.36864035])

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
hist,bin_edges,patches = 
ax1.hist(Ls,bins=20,density=True)
print("hist: ",hist)
#hist:  [1.67273235, 0.79653921, 0.15930784, 0., 0.,       
#0.,0., 0.,0.,0., 0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.15930784 
#0.07965392,0.,0.07965392]`
```

Comment: Your histogram gives values greater than 1. So yes.

Comment: But it is correct to to get values greater than 1? It is probability distribution so In was expecting values should be less than 1? Moreover area under the curve is also greater than 1 that is 1.000002.

Comment: The integral over the whole range is 1. Not sure where your number comes from, but you can easily just `print(np.sum(hist*np.diff(bin_edges)))` and get 1 out. There is no reason to expect the density to be smaller or equal to one - it is the integral which gives you the probability.

Comment: ok thanks. Ls are some normalized energy levels. In above Question I only mentioned Ls for one sample. I have 10 samples.  I  printed
 print(np.sum(hist*np.diff(bin_edges))), for some samples it is 0.99999, for 1 sample it is 1.000 and for 3rd sample it is 1.00000002. I have doubt for 1.000002 that is this value is acceptable? and why it is greater than 1?

Comment: Floating point inaccuracies can easily add up. Here you have a relative error of 2e-6%. This should be considered acceptable when using numpy on usual hardware.